# onLocationResult is not getting called

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-maps

I am following a tutorial where I am developing an app like Uber. When someone logs into the app as a diver the onLocationResult method should be called and in this method a record for the driver is placed in a firebase table called DriversAvailable. For some reason, this table is not getting created in my DB and I'm pretty sure its because the onLocationResult method is not called. In my onLocationResult method, there is a switch on a variable called customerID, if it is blank then the driver's location gets placed in the DriversAvailable table. customerID will be blank until a customer logs in and clicks the "call uber button" therefore when I am testing this with two phones and I log in as a driver I should see a record in the DriversAvailable with the driver's location as the child.

```
 LocationCallback Callback = new LocationCallback(){
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
            for(Location location : locationResult.getLocations()){
                if(getApplicationContext()!=null){

                    if(!customerID.equals("") && mLastLocation!=null && location != null){
                        rideDistance += mLastLocation.distanceTo(location)/1000;
                    }
                    mLastLocation = location;


                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));

                    String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
                    DatabaseReference refAvailable = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("DriversAvailable");
                    DatabaseReference refWorking = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("DriversWorking");
                    GeoFire geoFireAvailable = new GeoFire(refAvailable);
                    GeoFire geoFireWorking = new GeoFire(refWorking);

                    switch (customerID){
                        case "":
                            geoFireWorking.removeLocation(userId);
                            geoFireAvailable.setLocation(userId, new GeoLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
                            break;

                        default:
                            geoFireAvailable.removeLocation(userId);
                            geoFireWorking.setLocation(userId, new GeoLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
```